# Adding/Deleting Facebook Users to Facebook group through app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am trying add/remove a Facebook user from a facebook. I have read a couple of posts that say this is not possible, but the facebook api documentation seems to think it is.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/#invite_user

I have tried to use this in conjunction with the PHP SDK and I have had no luck. Here is my code:

```
    require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET'
));

$userID = $facebook->getUser();

if ($userID) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    $token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
            "client_id=APP_ID" .
            "&client_secret=APP_SECRET" .
            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
    $app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $app_tokenArray = explode("=", $app_token);
    $app_tokenF = $app_tokenArray[1];
    $facebook->setAccessToken($app_tokenF);
    ECHO "$app_token<br />";
    try {
      // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID/members/'.$userID,'DELETE');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
      ECHO $e;
      $userID = null;
    }
    ECHO $user_profile;
  }
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    $loginUrl .= "&scope=user_groups,friends_groups,create_event";
    ECHO "<a onclick=\"window.open('$loginUrl', '', 'width=900px, height=600px, top=20px, left=30px')\">Install App</a>";
}
```

The app appears to install fine, but when I return to it so that it executes the member removal I receive this error:

OAuthException: (#3)

I have tried several things and I am looking for any insight. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That document says you can only delete when using an app access token - your code here seems to be using a user access token - is that correct?

Comment: Whoops. My bad lgy. I have updated to show the proper code. I have tested it and had it fail with the same error code.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?